# Issue with sticky menu

Tags: html, css

I have a sticky menu on my wordpress site which is just a header with css position fixed but it's overlaying over the top of each of my sections. You can see what I mean if you view the test site [here](http://www.webcontrolcentre.co.uk/bluesource/)

if you click on the menu icon and click on a section it will navigate to each section but I need the sticky menu to rest above each section instead of it overlaying at the top.

In my header.php I have

```
<div id="header-wrap">

                    <div class="poweredby">POWERED BY bluesource<p class="mobile-phone"><a href="tel: +44 0845 319 2100">0845 319 2100</a></p></div>

                        <div class="headerphone">0845 319 2100</div>

                    <button class="toggle-menu menu-right push-body"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>

                        <!-- Right menu element-->

                        <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) || has_nav_menu( 'social' ) ) : ?>

                            <?php if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) : ?>

                                <nav id="site-navigation" class="cbp-spmenu cbp-spmenu-vertical cbp-spmenu-right" role="navigation" aria-label="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Primary Menu', 'twentysixteen' ); ?>">
                                    <?php
                                        wp_nav_menu( array(
                                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                                        'menu_class'     => 'primary-menu',
                                        ) );
                                    ?>
                                </nav> 

                            <?php endif; ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                </div><!-- end header wrap -->
```

In my stylesheet I have

```
.site-header {
background: #333 none repeat scroll 0 0;
height: 98px;
padding: 27px 0;
text-align: right;
}

.site-header-main {
    text-align: right;
    right: 0;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 27px;
}

#header-wrap {
    background: #333;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
    height: 98px;
    padding-top: 27px;
    padding-right: 27px;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will do it

```
$('#header-wrap ul li a').click(function(){
    href=$(this).attr('href');
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(href).offset().top-98  // since the height of your nav is 98px
    }, 500);
});
```

For external links

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var urlHash = window.location.href.split("#")[1];
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#' + urlHash).offset().top-98 
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: This works great on my homepage using my nav links so thankyou but just wondering how i can get it to work using a link from another page? I have links on a second page that link back to a certain section on the homepage so I used your code above but changed #header-wrap ul li a to .entry-content a but it doesn't work?

Comment: This is brilliant, works exactly how I want but just a bit curious that when i click on the external link back to the home page it doesn't animate, it's not an issue and works but just wondering why?

Comment: @Duggy G have you added second code to the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job. I increased the position right so you get the white bar along the side, I applied an important tag otherwise it gets overwritten.

```
nav#site-navigation {
    top: 98px;
}
.cbp-spmenu-right.menu-open {
    right: 23px !important;
}
```